# How to convert int column in time "HH:MM" in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

how can I convert **int "Hour"** and **Int "Minute"** into time and then get percentages of two different time?

to get total of time from **int** column I am using

```
Format((SUM([THOURS]) * 3600 + SUM([TMINUTES]) * 60 + SUM([TSECONDS])) / 3600,'00')+':'+Format((SUM([THOURS]) * 3600 + SUM([TMINUTES]) * 60 + SUM([TSECONDS])) % 3600/60,'00') as "Total Time"
```

I got the perfect time from the above query.

But now i wan to get percentage calculation from my two **int "Hour"** and **Int "Minute"**  column table. 
[image]

I have tried

```
DECLARE @MS INT = 235216
select cast(dateadd(ms, @MS, '00:00:00') AS TIME(3))
```

it's not working as my requirement.

Is anyone have an idea for same?

Comment: "it's not working as my requirement" ...so what's your requirement? What _exactly_ do you want the output to be?

Comment: Also, for future reference, you should post DDL and data as **text** in your question, not as a picture.  Pictures are quick and easy, but they require the people here (unpaid volunteers) to transcribe things manually.

Comment: is any way to convert my int value to time? dateadd calculating my int value which is already final time.

Comment: "It's not working as my requirement" without telling us your requirement will not help us help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your time fields into minutes, and then do the math on the minutes.  This example uses two variables - you'd use your field names instead.

```
Declare
    @Allotted As Time = '08:00'
    , @Taken As Time = '06:00'

    Select Cast(DateDiff(Minute, '00:00', @Taken) As Numeric(17, 2)) / DateDiff(Minute, '00:00', @Allotted) as Percent_Of_Allotted_Time
```

Comment: You're very welcome.  If that solved your problem, please mark is answer as "accepted" - I'm told that that will make it easier for others to find.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help:

```
declare @A table 
  ( xHours int, xMinutes int, xSeconds int, 
    yHours int, yMinutes int, ySeconds int  )

insert into @A ( xHours, xMinutes, xSeconds, yHours, yMinutes, ySeconds ) values
( 7, 23, 59, 13, 44, 51 ),
( 0, 00, 12,  1, 07, 00 );

with A as ( select *, 
            3600 * xHours + 60 * xMinutes + xSeconds as xTotal,
            3600 * yHours + 60 * yMinutes + ySeconds as yTotal 
            from @A ),
B as ( select *, 
       cast ( DATEADD(second,xTotal,'00:00:00') as time(0)) as xTime,
       cast ( DATEADD(second,yTotal,'00:00:00') as time(0)) as yTime
 from A ),
C as ( select *, 100*CAST(xTotal as float)/CAST(yTotal as float) as Usage from B )
select xTotal, yTotal, xTime, yTime, Usage from C
```

Result:

```
xTotal  yTotal     xTime     yTime  Usage
 26639   49491  07:23:59  13:44:51  53.8259481521893
    12    4020  00:00:12  01:07:00  0.298507462686567
```